# how to add timestamp for the file name when file is uploading

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

This is a related java code for upload file code and i need to add a timestamp for a file name and then it is uploaded to the particular directory

```
 public class Upload extends HttpServlet {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   public void init() throws ServletException {

     System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
   }

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     //boolean MultipartRequest;
     //String PrintWriter;

     response.setContentType("text/html");

     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "/home/hadoop/Desktop");

     out.println("succcesfully uploaded");

   }
   public void destroy() {
     System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
   }

 }
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Selectfile:
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you want timestamp as the File name , is it so ?

Comment: get the `timestamp` then make a file with the `samename_timestamp` and upload both of them. Or add a line at the end within the file

Comment: @Alok Mishra  i need samefilename_timestamp.extention

Comment: @UmaKanth: Surely you mean timestamp_filename?  In yyyyMM... format.

Answer (score 3):

[MultipartRequest](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html) by default contains a file rename policy.

> To avoid collisions and have fine control over file placement, there's a constructor variety that takes a pluggable FileRenamePolicy implementation. A particular policy can choose to rename or change the location of the file before it's written.

```
MultipartRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                 java.lang.String saveDirectory, 
                 int maxPostSize, 
                 FileRenamePolicy policy)
```

Note: Due to low reputation, I can't add comments and had to contribute this as an answer. Don't downvote this, instead correct or comment on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Simply concat `"_" + System.currentTimeMillis()` to the filename ?

If instead of the milliseconds you want the intellegible timestamp, simply use a DateFormat as shown in the other answer.

With Java EE >= 6:

```
@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,    // 10 MB 
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,          // 50 MB
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)      // 100 MB
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        String uploadFilePath = applicationPath + File.separator + "uploads";              
        File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) { fileSaveDir.mkdirs(); }

        String fileName = null;
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            fileName = getFileName(part) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis(); // <----- HERE
            part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        request.setAttribute("message", fileName + " File uploaded successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }      
    private String getFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

The code is a fork of the one in [this article](http://www.journaldev.com/2122/servlet-3-file-upload-using-multipartconfig-annotation-and-part-interface)

Comment: in my code where i need to add this "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Your code is not doing anything... if you want to write it by your own, then use the code in my answer; if you want to use that oreilly wrapper, then use @Gopal's answer, otherwise consider using something more evoluted than a servlet, like a framework (eg. Struts2).

Answer (score 0):

Get the current date and time and append it to your file name while uploading.

```
private  final static String getDateTime()
{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // mention your timezone
    return df.format(new Date());
}
```

Now append the returned string in the filename.